# SQL: WHERE clause multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    ((1.0 * (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) 
             FROM RawData r
             INNER JOIN Product p ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
             WHERE p.Distributor = 'TF1', 'WARNER')
GROUP BY p.Distributor)
/
(SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)*100)
;
```

The above query gives an error:

```
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Could anyone point out what the issue is? I know for a fact that I cant use OR/AND condition in this case.
The result set has to have 2 rows.

Product:

```
Distributor     
  WARNER              
  TF1                 
  WARNER              
  TF1
```

RawData:

```
   SalesVolume
        5
        6
        3
        4
```

Comment: You are wrong; you must use OR/AND (or the shorthand IN).

Answer (score 2):

perhaps `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT
((1.0*(SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER'))
/
(SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)*100)
;
```

Comment: I had to add the group by clause as well. So the modified query is `SELECT
(1.0*(SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')GROUP BY p.Distributor)
/
(SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)*100)
;
` However now I get `Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @TauseefHussain show some dummy data so it will clear what you want

Comment: @TauseefHussain what are you expecting as the output?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
WHERE p.Distributor IN ('TF1','WARNER')
```